# VS Code debugger freezes and stop receiving requests

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My VS Code is acting quite weird lately.

Let's begin with how it works properly: if I'm constantly using my project (Python) and reloading the pages it works the way it supposed to, with no issues at all.

How it doesn't: after a while (10 minutes or so) with no requests (like I'm working on my code), if I reload the webpage, it simply won't respond to the requests. Each new request puts a new thread on hold, but the debug console won't show any new request, just stays there frozen.
I just found out that if I reload the page like 10 times it will begin to respond again, but that's quite annoying.

I tried to search a lot on the web but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: What kind of application are you actually debugging?